Python Alembic codec cant decode byte
Ошибка:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 61: 
invalid continuation byte

При попытке миграции в postresql выдает эту ошибку,
смотрел другие решения, не помогло. 
Имя компьютера на английском, код обычный alembic за исключением ссылки на юрл
sqlalchemy(sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://%(DB_USER)s:%(DB_PASS)s@%(DB_HOST)s:%(DB_PORT)s/%(DB_NAME)s)

